# How can I listen for focusIn and focusOut events for a Spark TextArea?

Tags: apache-flex, focus, textarea, event-listener

I am writing a flex application and I have two Spark TextAreas.  I want to create an EventListener so that when the user clicks on a text area, the text inside the TextArea is cleared:

```
this.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);


   private function onFocusIn(ev:FocusEvent):void {
        if (this._showsCaption) {
            this._showsCaption = false;
            super.text = "";
        }
    }
```

Currently I can implement this with a Spark TextInput, but when I click on the TextArea, the focusIn event never fires and the onFocusIn() handler is never called.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are extending the TextArea (as in your case), you can override the protected "focusInHandler" method. This is the handler that is called when the control gets focus. The same goes for the "focusOutHandler" method.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#focusInHandler()

Comment: Thanks - that was the answer I'm looking for.  I'd vote up but I'm brand new to StackOverflow and don't have the privileges